# Postcode Distance using imap

Tags: r

I have two data set one contains one set of postcodes along with their "Lat" and "Lon". I want to create a matrix of distance for all postcodes in one data set with all postcodes of other data set.

```
df.postcodes <- data.frame(name = c("21075", "20099", "33613"),lat  = c( 53.459940,  53.5580847,52.0454598),lon = c(9.9288308,10.0119789,8.5196291))
df.postcodes1 <- data.frame(name = c("210751", "200991"),lat  = c( 55.459940,  52.5580847),
                       lon = c(10.9288308,11.0119789))
```

This is sample data set, so basically i want to create a distance matrix for all postcodes in df.postcodes1 with all the postcodes in df.postcodes and then return the nearest postcode. 
I heard of this package `Imap` but I am unable to create a matrix from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I am using `gdist` from package `Imap` to compute the geo distance between 2 points.

To get a matrix of distance beteween all the points of set A to the points in set B you can use `outer` ( or `expand.grid` but `outer` is better here since you want a matrix as a result). `outer` will generates all index for you(cartesian product of 2 sets).

Finally you should vectorize `gdist` because `outer` expcted a vectorized function. I do this using `mapply`( You can use `Vectorize`).

```
library(Imap)

## a vectorized version of `gdist`
## x and y are vectors of index 
dist_imap <- 
function(x,y){
  p1 <- df.postcodes[x,]
  p2 <- df.postcodes1[y,]
  mapply(gdist,p1$lon,p1$lat,p2$lon,p2$lat)
}
## Use index of rows since we have to loop over data.frames
X <- seq_len(nrow(df.postcodes))
Y <- seq_len(nrow(df.postcodes1))
## outer will generate all comobination of index 
## and pply the vectorized function already created.
res <- outer(X,Y,dist_imap)
## naming for pretty output
rownames(res)  <- df.postcodes$name
colnames(res) <- df.postcodes1$name

#         210751   200991
# 21075 125.2018 66.91572
# 20099 118.7207 70.15158
# 33613 222.3866 96.82441
```

Comment: This works for me, but this code loses out the column name and row name, can we also get in place of column name the postcode of df.postcodes1 and in row name the postcodes df.postcodes , so it becomes clear as to which postcodes its giving the distance?